# Disk Read Function not Working as Expected in Bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I'm trying to develop a basic bootloader, but I ran into a problem when I tried to create a function for reading additional sectors from a hard drive. I'm developing it on Kali Linux in NASM and using QEMU as my emulator.
This is my main bootloader file:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

call read_disk

mov si, my_string
call print          ;prints a string, si points to the string to be printed

jmp $

read_disk
    mov ah, 0x02    ;read from disk
    mov al, 0x01    ;read one sector
    mov ch, 0x00    ;read from cylinder 0
    mov dh, 0x00    ;read from head 0
    mov cl, 0x02    ;read the second sector

    mov bx, 0
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, 0x7c00+512

    int 0x13

    jc disk_error   ;BIOS sets the carry flag if disk read was unsuccessful

    ret

disk_error:
    mov si, error_msg
    call print
    jmp $
;
;Functions
;
%include "functions/print.asm"
%include "functions/print_hex.asm"
%include "functions/print_nl.asm"
%include "functions/calc_len.asm"
%include "functions/find_string.asm"

;
;Data
;
error_msg:
    db 'Error reading disk', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0    ;pad out the rest of the bootloader with zeros to increase the size to 512 bytes
dw 0xaa55                ;Magic bytes so BIOS recognizes the hard drive as bootable

;
;SECOND SECTOR
;

my_string:
    db 'Disk read successful', 0

times 512 db 0   ;need to pad out the rest of the sector with zeros since  QEMU requires it
```

As you can see, `my_string` lies after 512 bytes, in the second sector of the emulated hard drive. But when I compile and run the bootloader, it doesn't output anything. In the code I provided above, I'm printing `my_string` *after* the `read_disk` function is over. But strangely enough, If I move the two lines that print `my_string` *inside* the function, it works.
This is the code that works:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

call read_disk

jmp $

read_disk
    mov ah, 0x02    ;read from disk
    mov al, 0x01    ;read one sector
    mov ch, 0x00    ;read from cylinder 0
    mov dh, 0x00    ;read from head 0
    mov cl, 0x02    ;read the second sector

    mov bx, 0
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, 0x7c00+512

    int 0x13

    jc disk_error   ;BIOS sets the carry flag if disk read was unsuccessful

    mov si, my_string
    call print          ;prints a string, si points to the string to be printed

    ret

disk_error:
    mov si, error_msg
    call print
    jmp $
;
;Functions
;
%include "functions/print.asm"
%include "functions/print_hex.asm"
%include "functions/print_nl.asm"
%include "functions/calc_len.asm"
%include "functions/find_string.asm"

;
;Data
;
error_msg:
    db 'Error reading disk', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0    ;pad out the rest of the bootloader with zeros to increase the size to 512 bytes
dw 0xaa55                ;Magic bytes so BIOS recognizes the hard drive as bootable

;
;SECOND SECTOR
;

my_string:
    db 'Disk read successful', 0

times 512 db 0   ;need to pad out the rest of the sector with zeros since  QEMU requires it
```

I'd be very grateful if someone can explain this strange oddity to me.

Comment: QEMU lets you attach a debugger like GDB; use it to see where execution goes.  That's half the point of using an emulator.  It would have revealed that `ret` was going somewhere you didn't want, giving a big hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set *SS:SP* and not just as *SP* before reading into memory. *SS* may be zero or it may not be. If *SS* happens to be 0x0000 then your stack is at 0x0000:0x8000 and it will grow down from there.

Your code reads the second 512 byte sector on the disk to memory at 0x0000:0x7e00 which includes all the bytes up to and including the return address of the `disk_read` function that was placed on the stack at 0x0000:0x7ffe to 0x0000:0x7fff.

Since you clobbered the stack, the `int 0x13` will likely never return because the internal data, return address and the flags have been corrupted. Corrupting the stack like this will have unpredictable results. Consider putting the stack at 0x0000:0x7c00 below the bootloader so as to not interfere with the data and code you load after the bootloader.

Note: You should set all the segment registers you need to values you expect. You shouldn't rely on any of the segment registers containing a specific value. The BIOS doesn't guarantee their values, although in most emulators they will be 0x0000.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for the help. But I can't help but wonder why no tutorial ever mentioned it and why it worked for everyone else. I couldn't find the same question as mine anywhere else, even though QEMU is really popular. Why did it work for others?

Comment: @0xSkid It depends on the tutorial. If the tutorial placed the stack at 0x0000:0x8000 but read to memory above 0x8000 then the stack wouldn't be clobbered. The other possibility is that the tutorial didn't place the stack at 0x0000:0x8000 (I'd have to see a link to a tutorial to know). The other possibility is that the tutorial you were using was buggy.

Comment: Here's the link: https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf
You need to look on the page 28 of the document.
The author of the document also made a video playlist for the same topic. I just went to rewatch it and it seems he set the stack at 0x0000:0xffff, but didn't say anything about it, so I didn't notice.

Comment: @0xSkid : That first example works because it doesn't load any data.code from disk into memory so the stack isn't clobbered below 0x8000. It simply prints out to the display.  If you look at the example in that tutorial that does the disk read they change the stack to be 0x9000 (from 0x8000). By doing that the disk read won't clobber the stack.